# Ubuntu: cron на ubuntu не пишет логи, в чем может быть причина?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, cron, планировщик-задач

У меня Ubuntu 20.04 на WSL 2. Возникла проблема с кроном. Не запускает написанные в crontab задания. Пытаюсь включить log по этому адресу: etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

К сожалению после многочисленных запусков php скриптов, например, так:
46 * * * * usr/bin/wget -q /var/www/auth/hello.php

Sudo service cron status дает что демон running

crontab -l говорит о том, что задание поставлено, причем поставлено именно тому пользователю, под которым я сижу.

В логах по-прежнему ничего: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Крон установлен.. проверил..

Comment: grep CRON /var/log/syslog смотрите  сюда по логам крона. Только суть задачи у вас в чем? Мне кажется, вам нужно создать crontab от юзера www-data. А зачем вы добавляете ключ -q ? wget -q

Comment: @user334685 /var/log/syslog такой папки нет у меня, к сожалению. У меня есть crontab от sudo пользователя... команда видна для него поcrontab -I, перехожу в этого пользователя Sudo -i, но в нужно время задание не выполняется и логи не пишутся..

Comment: запустить в консоли wget, может у вас нет этого инструмента.

Comment: да, поробую, но я до этого и интерпретатором php пробовал..

Comment: @user334685 c php интерпретатором тот же результат, но он точно есть, я проверил..

Comment: @user334685 сделал sudo ps -A | grep, результат, причем последняя надпись "cron" красного цвета: cron 30944 ?        00:00:00 cron